# Are there quantum modifications to the rules of special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Are there corrections to special relativity due to quantum mechanics? For example a modification of Lorentz transform involving $\hbar $ terms, or an alternate form of Einstein's energy matter equation like

$$ E= (m+\hbar \delta )c^2 $$

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question, which is generally considered off-topic as *too broad* as any response could be considered as an answer. Please see the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for details of what types of questions to avoid asking.

Answer (score 1):

In relativistic quantum mechanics wavefunctions, equations and conserved quantities are Lorentz covariant. So the answer is no.

As to the equation you display, it is new to me. Do you have a reference to a textbook or article in which it is discussed?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better to say relativity modified quantum mechanics, giving relativistic QM & ultimately QFT.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the "not an answer" flag here: even though it is brief, this post seems to fit better as an answer to the question than as a comment on how to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a school of thought that suggests that one thing that could modify Lorentz symmetries is quantum gravity. And so Planck mass (or energy etc.), rather than simply $\hbar$ should enter such modified equations.

For example [doubly special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_special_relativity):

> a modified theory of special relativity in which there is not only an observer-independent maximum velocity (the speed of light), but an observer-independent maximum energy scale and minimum length scale (the Planck energy and Planck length).

For more details:

> Amelino-Camelia, G. (2010). Doubly-special relativity: facts, myths and some key open issues. Symmetry, 2(1), 230-271, [doi](https://doi.org/0.3390/sym2010230), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3942)